# Assert vs Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I have read about when to use assert and when to use an exception.

Assertions are intended to be used as a means of detecting programming errors, aka bugs. Some say assert is for debugging purposes only and its trigger condition should not happen.

By contrast, an exception can indicate other kinds of error or "exceptional" condition: invalid user input, missing files, heap full, etc. From my understanding, exceptions can do everything asserts can do except they cannot be disabled.

If all asserts were replaced by exceptions, it would be functionally the same. So, is the ability to disable asserts the only reason why they should be used or are there other reasons?

Thanks.

Comment: You can catch and throw any `Throwable` in Java, they are the same from that standpoint.

Comment: Think of an assertion as "check & possibly an exception" vs a simple "exception".  So it's a short-cut that for that logic, as well as a clear declaration (self-documenting code) that an specific condition is being "asserted to be true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two use cases for assertions in production code:

At the beginning of a method you would normaly check if the given parameter are valid. For public methods you would use if statments and exceptions. For private methods you would make the simelar checks using assert. The idea is to avoid redundant checks in produktion while in testing (or when somesting goes wrong) you can just activate assertions to do some double checking.

The other reason to use assertions is to document the assumptions that are used in the following code. Like that some value is considered never to be null here.

Here some example code

```
public class Exampel {
    public publicMethod(final Integer i) {
        if (i == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("i should not be null");
        }

        privateMethod(i):
    }

    private privateMethod(final Integer i) {
        assert i != null;

        // do something
    }
}
```

You would not want to check i for null several times. You would just assume that `privateMethod`is used correctly. You also give anyone that reads your code the hint that passing null to `privateMethod`is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: avoid redundant checks in produktion - I would call this flagship answer. Thanks, and thanks to everyone to help me out here

Answer (score 3):

Asserts are used by test cases to make sure that what you built doesn't, in the future, render something unexpected. You can assert to make sure exceptions are thrown upon false input, for instance.

Many times in programming changing one thing means you have to change other pieces of your code. Assertations make sure that what you change doesn't break code you've written in the past.

Exceptions are good. They are expected and handled via exceptions. You have exceptions for incorrect login and password, for instance.

You can assert that upon an incorrect login or password, the expected exception is raised.

An assert contains three main things. What you're testing (function name for instance, i.e. `sign_in`), what goes in (function parameters i.e. `{'email': 'john@example.com', 'password': hashlib.md5('my_password')}`), and what comes out (`assertTrue('user_name' in response, 'Expecting user_name to be in response!')`).

Exceptions are normal, logical alternatives in code. Asserts are tests to make sure logical paths are followed when they should be.

According to the python [unittest framework](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html), you can assert that exceptions are thrown:

```
import random import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))

        # should raise an exception for an immutable sequence
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, random.shuffle, (1,2,3))


    def test_choice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def test_sample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            random.sample(self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Every assert can be replaced with an exceptions. It would be interested in knowing 'why' to use them rather than when or where. Example: "You can assert to make sure exceptions are thrown upon false input," - but I can use exceptions too .. so why use asserts ?

Comment: Nope. Exceptions should never replace asserts. Asserts are used to assert an exception. Asserts are used to assert normal input, output. Asserts facilitate the assurance of exceptions.

Comment: Throw a custom exception when that user is not found (UserNotFoundException). Then write an assert to make sure it's thrown, for instance.

Comment: Think of a flow chart. The arrow gets to the diamond or decision part in the flow chart. It can go left if the decision is yes, or right if the decision is no. Left if the user entered in a correct username and password combination, right if the user didn't. These are normal, logical conditions you want to write two asserts for. One assert to test the left side and one assert to test the right side.

Comment: You're welcome :) cheers to assertions!

Comment: It is important to distinguish, however, when to use exceptions and when to use assertions. I think you get it, given your comment to the answer you chose. It might be good practice, at least in python/javascript, to keep your assert statements *separate* from your exceptions. This allows you to keep your test statements separate from your operation logic.

Answer (score 2):

assertions are designed to be selectively turned off, and by default they are off.  You should use them when there are conditions which should never be the case, but can be checked if you really need to.  Think of them as more exceptional than exceptions.

Exceptions and their checks are always on.  While exceptional they could still occur at any time.

Assertions can check coding errors and once you program is bug free they shouldn't be needed.  Exceptions can be triggered due to values which may not be under you control such as inputs.

Comment: I tend to think of them as having a documentation function as well - they're a way of specifying the contract (input arguments must meet these criteria, the object's state must have these characteristics, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Asserts in working code, as opposed to test code, are there to check that the values supplied to the code are correct. If the values are wrong, an assertion exception is thrown.

You can write your own code to test the values and throw an exception of your own choosing.

Assertions are easy to use and, like logging, can be turned off in production code that has been thoroughly debugged. Also, anyone reading the code knows why the test is there without thinking about it. So it saves them time. (It will save you time too when you go back and read the code you wrote two years ago.)

Either way works.

Answer (score 1):

Many programmer convert asserts into exception checks in release code. Or they might use two different kinds of asserts in order to convert one and not the others, if some happen to be very performance sensitive.

This is part of defensive programming. Asserts should document impossible conditions. However, real life programmers know that impossible conditions do sometimes happen, because of untested code paths, bugs in system libraries, or hardware errors.

There is usually very little harm in converting asserts into exceptions. Some harm that could happen is in Java, it could introduce a new exception type into a method that previously didn't have one. Another harm might be that a converted assert could be inside of a loop that requires very high performance, and the assert check might slow it down too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main difference is that asserts allow you to see that a problem has occurred earlier than an exception would. So it gives you an earlier point in execution to attempt to do something about it (or maybe nothing at all - let it fail). So you would use them if you want to see how execution is going before something really bad happens (an exception is thrown).

One dramatic analogy I can think of are those Soyuz delivery rockets to ISS, occasionally you hear that an automated rocket went off course at start and immediately triggered its "self destruct". I would guess that its something like an assert that they use to determine if the heading of the rocket is correct (if it was an exception - by the time that could be thrown the rocket might already hit something).

Answer (score 0):

assertions are designed to be selectively turned off, and by default they are off.  You should use them when there are conditions which should never be the case, but can be checked if you really need to.  Think of them as more exceptional than exceptions.

Exceptions and their checks are always on.  While exceptional they could still occur at any time.

assertions detect coding errors.  Once your program is bug free they shouldn't be needed and can be turned off.  Exceptions detect incorrect usage or inputs and cannot be safely turned off.